# Linear Independence And Diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

When we say that a linear map $T:V\to V$ where $\dim(V)=n$ has a $n$ linear independent vectors so $T$ can be diagonalisable we refer not to every $n$ linear independent vectors, it must be the eigenvectors? as

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ has linear independent vectors but it is not diagonalisable

Comment: I do not fully understand your question.  An $n\times n$ matrix $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if there exists an invertible matrix $S$ and a diagonal matrix $D$ such that $T=SDS^{-1}$ and this is true if and only if the sum of the geometric multiplicities of the eigenvalues is equal to $n$, i.e. iff $T$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

Comment: @newhere Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2):

Recall that to diagonalize a n-by n matrix what we need is a basis of $n$ (independent) eigenvectors.

Note also that we don't need independent columns vectors (or rows) for a matrix to be diagonalizable, as for example

\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}

which is of course in diagonal form.

Refer also to [Diagonalizable matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the key point:

> $T:V \to V$ where $\dim V=n$ is diagonizable if and only if there are $n$ linearly
>   independent vectors that are all eigenvectors of $T$.

Not just any vectors will do. Your example

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

has only one eigenvalue $\lambda=1$. Note all eigenvectors are non-zeor solutions to the equation $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. Calculate the following:
$$
A-1I=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

It should be clear that the only possible eigenvector has form $v=t\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ for some non-zero $t$. Thus it's impossible to find $2$ linearly indepndent eigenvectors for $A$